# Debug window in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter

I just started using jupyter for a python project. I constantly find myself adding an extra cell just to perform some basic try&error debugging. This way I omit the whole code of the cell is being executed but it still doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

Does Jupyter provide something like a static kernel terminal, for example always visible at the bottom of the screen, where I can simply paste code and execute runtime variables?

By the way: I did search but didn't find anything looking for static console, and terminal. Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `jupyter console` command will provide you with an interpreter environment that you can experiment with code running within the Jupyter environment outside of a notebook.

It's not exactly what you're looking for but may provide a better environment for testing and developing code that you can then paste into the appropriate notebook.